# VBA issue, with a simplistic twist

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

This is code right out of Excel 2013 Power Programming and, for some reason, I can't get it to work.

This script is right out of the box, but it doesn't work:

```
Sub SayHello()
  Msg "Is your name " & Application.UserName & "?"
  Ans = MsgBox(Meg, vbYesNo)
  If Ans = vsNO Then
    MsgBox "Oh, nevermind then.  Bother"
  Else
    MsgBox "I must be clairvoyant!"
  End If 
End Sub
```

I get a Compile error:
`Sub or Function not defined`
on the start line of the sub

This is my first experience with VBA, so be gentle if I did something very stupid.

Comment: `Msg = "Is your name " & Application.UserName & "?"` (note equals sign added). Then `Msg` not `Meg`.

Comment: You should also get into the habit of declaring your variables. Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This 
will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct var type in the variable 
declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant/object type. Using **Option Explicit** is 
considered 'best practice'.

Comment: Good suggestions, Jeeped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple typos and missing =

```
Sub SayHello()
    Msg = "Is your name " & Application.UserName & "?"
    Ans = MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo)
    If Ans = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Oh, nevermind then."
    Else
        MsgBox "I must be clairvoyant!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Tested and working in Excel 2010

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that crap.